# ASP.Net Core OpenAPI Generated HttpClient not injecting

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, openapi

I have an OpenApi client generated via adding connected services in visual studio 2019. i'm trying to inject it via my startup using below:

```
   //Add Http Client
        services.AddHttpClient<IConfigurationClient,ConfigurationClient>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["ApiConfigs:Configurations:Uri"]);
        });
```

But when i try to use this client in my Controller i get the following error.

```
public ConfigurationController(ILogger<ConfigurationController> logger, IConfigurationClient configClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configClient = configClient;
    }
```

Error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'ConfigurationApi.ConfigurationClient'.
```

Any idea why this is happening. when i directly create an instance of COnfigurationClient by passing a new HttpClient the same works.

The Implementation of ConfigurationClient

```
public partial class ConfigurationClient : IConfigurationClient
{
    private string _baseUrl = "";
    private System.Net.Http.HttpClient _httpClient;
    private System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings> _settings;

    public ConfigurationClient(string baseUrl, System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        BaseUrl = baseUrl; 
        _httpClient = httpClient; 
        _settings = new System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings>(() => 
        {
            var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
            UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(settings);
            return settings;
        });
    }
```

}

Please note its auto generated (ConfigurationClient) by VisualStudio (NSWAG)

Thanks

Comment: Show the configuration client implementation. It's constructor has a string parameter that the container is unable to resolve.

Comment: @Nkosi i have added the constructor of client implementation

Comment: Where is that base Url string used in the class? That should be removed from the class since it really should be configured in the start like how you currently have it

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs because .NET is not able to provide the dependency for "string baseUrl" in the generated client. To fix, you need to disable `UseBaseUrl` as part of the client generation. Here's the config I use:

```xml
<OpenApiReference Include="swagger.json" SourceUrl="https://example.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json">
  <Namespace>Configuration</Namespace>
  <ClassName>ConfigurationClient</ClassName>
  <OutputPath>ConfigurationClient.cs</OutputPath>
  <Options>/UseBaseUrl:false /GenerateClientInterfaces:true</Options>
</OpenApiReference>
```